# Request certificate generate button not showing

Tags: ios, csr

I'm about to get my first certificate as an Apple iOS developer. I go ahead and follow instructions, go to keychain, create the CSR, and upload it to the website. When I press "Upload" and select the CSR from the desktop, the generate button doesn't even turn clickable! It doesn't turn clickable even though I press "Upload" and select my CSR file many many times.

What did I do wrong? I followed the instructions to the letter, and my internet connection is great?

Any ideas on what might be happening to me?

Comment: are you using safari? I never accessed it from other browser, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: I SOLVED IT!

The reason why the "generate" button is not responding is because I was using firefox. Never use firefox when uploading a CSR because for some reason it doesn't communicate well with keychain. 

The reason why i used firefox is because in safari, the "add" certificate button wouldn't even work at all! The reason for this is that my version of Safari is old. You need to update your version of safari to the latest to be able to use Apple Developer website smoothly.

Comment: And also, when you use safari and you get "invalid certificate" after pressing generate. There is another problem there too. You need to download the world wide certificate into your keychain before you even generate the CSR, otherwise, you would always get the invalid certificate warning.